# How to map data from Parent table to its child table on change function

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

I created a function that map data into child table when some fields changes in parent table, data saves in child table when parent table fields changes I can see it in the db, but  the problem is data doesn't display in tree grid view of child table.

Here is my code :

```
def on_change_test(self, cr, uid, ids, district_id,
                   select_db,sub_district_id,ward, context = None):
    obj_master = self.pool.get('Parent_table')
    MasterID = obj_master.create(cr, uid,
              {'district_id':district_id,
               'sub_district_id':sub_district_id,
               'to_master_ward':ward, 
               'select_db':select_db})
        obj_child = self.pool.get('Child_table') 
        obj_child.create(cr, uid,
                        {'sex':'male',
                         'wardID':MasterID, 
                         'from_ward':child_line_id.address_id.name,
                         'Parent_ID':child_line_id.id,
                         'date_o_birth':child_line_id.date_of_birth})      
    return True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
    obj_master = super(parent_table,self).create(cr,uid, vals, context=context)
    obj_child = self.pool.get('child.table') 
    obj_child.create(cr, uid,{'field_name':obj_child.field_value......})
```

your method is not correct , you can do it by overriding the create method with a super call